# How to pivot survey/questionnaire data and count multiple option questions?

Tags: python, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a survey with many questions all sharing the same levels.
Basically I want to pivot from this:

| Customer | Atribute 1 | Atribute 2 | Atribute 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | A |
| 2 | B | B | A |
| 3 | C | B | C |

To this:

| Product | Atribute 1 | Atribute 2 | Atribute 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 1 |

In my real data I have dozens of columns and levels (A, B, C...Z) and hundreds of customers.
I was once able to do this in R but it was years ago with an overcomplicated algorithm. I'm wondering if Python/pandas has an easy fix for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your DataFrame named `df`, then you can do it in this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int).drop("Customer" , axis=1).rename_axis("Product")
```

this gives me:
[image]